# how to upload image with form data with ionic angular.js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, image-uploading, ngcordova, image-upload

Hi I am trying to upload image with the rest of the form data in ionic angular.js for my mobile application. I am using ngCordova plugin. But didnt find any document for this procees.

Example: 
I have registration form in this form has to enter his details and upload profile image. But as the example i cant send all data to the server in one request.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To upload image to the server using Ionic 2 Framework, you have to use the Transfer plugin. Install transfer plugin using

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer`

Then call the upload function from Transfer class.

```
const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}

  }

 fileTransfer.upload(imageDataLocalURL, 'http://localhost/ionic/upload.php',  options1)
.then((data) => {
 // success
 alert("success");
}, (err) => {
 // error
 alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Use the link to know more https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/upload-an-image-to-the-php-server-using-ionic-2-transfer-and-camera-plugin

**Updated at 26-FEB-2018**

**For Ionic 3 , The File Transfer plugin had some changes.**

To install File Transfer plugin

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/file-transfer`

And the classes renamed to FileTransfer from Transfer in Ionic version 3.

`import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } 
from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';`

For complete demo, visit the below link.

https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-3/upload-image-to-the-php-server-using-ionic-3-file-transfer-and-camera-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $cordovaFileTransfer for this. The specific implementation is described here : [Upload image to server angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101940/upload-image-to-server-angularjs)

You can either upload an image from the local storage or an image taken with the camera plugin.